# How to create array using customize value?

Tags: php, arrays

I have some values below:

11 12 13.

I need to make an array using this value. 
array(11,12,13);

I tried this code below :

```
$selected is the variable that contain the value 11 12 13 //Special Instruction
foreach($selected as $key=>$val)
{
  $sel.=$val;
  $sel.=",";
}
 $str = rtrim($sel,',');
 // echo $str;
 $shortlist = array_map('trim', explode(',',$str));
```

I need help to make an array like array(11,12,13).Any idea?

Comment: Is `11 12 13` a string? Or an array with three items?

Comment: Is your input a string? If so, what separates 11 from 12? Is the question on an assumption that all substrings are 2-char length?

Answer (score 0):

try `str_split` see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

```
$str = "111213";

$array = str_split($str, 2);

print_r($array);
```

output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 13
)
```

Comment: I m getting the value without white space.Getting value something like.In that case what should I do?

Comment: try this $array = str_split($str, 2);

Answer (score 0):

```
$values = explode(' ', "11 12 13");

// if there is no space, you can do it like this
$strLen = strlen($string);
$i = 0;
while($i < $strLen) {
  $myArr[] = substr($string, $i, 2);
  $i += 2;
}
print_r($myArr);
```

Comment: I m getting the value without white space.Getting value something like.In that case what should I do?

Comment: for string without space you can do it as above. i have not checked it though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) here. [split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) is deprecated in latest version.

```
$str = "11 12 13";
$array = explode(" ",$str);
```

Comment: I m getting the value without white space.Getting value something like.In that case what should I do?

Comment: What is your actual case please mention in your question. You get answer according to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$selected = "11 12 13";

print_r (explode(" ",$selected));
```